# How to scroll Jetpack Compose screen that overflows its contents?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-orientation, android-scroll

I have an Add Shopping List item Jetpack Compose screen which contains several `TextField` inputs and an image container at the bottom. The screen overflows at the bottom and is cut off. How can I scroll the screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT: October 2023**

At some point along the way this was changed and the old solution does not work anymore. The solution to this question is now:

```kotlin
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
...
Column( // or whatever your parent composable is
    modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
) {
    ...
}
```

**Old solution**

Add `Modifier.scrollable(..)` to the container that you wish to make scrollable.
Code would be something like this:

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
...
Box( // or whatever your parent composable is
    modifier = Modifier
        .scrollable(state = scrollState, orientation = Orientation.Vertical)
) {
    ...
}
```

Of course, there are other `Modifier` methods for making composables scrollable that might fit better for your case.

Comment: this does not work for me with compose version 1.3.3

Comment: same here not working

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 2):

If the approved answer is not working try like below

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

Column(
    modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
) { 
    ...
}
```

Do not forget to apply it to your parent composable

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modifier `verticalScroll` on your container to achieve this.

```kotlin
Column(
  modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState())
) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**